# NDO2DB does not start

Tags: nagios

When I run ndo2db its give me error :

```
Starting ndo:Error processing config file '/usr/local/nagios/etc/ndo2db.cfg'.
 done.
```

My `ndo2db.conf` file looks like this:

```
lock_file=/usr/local/nagios/var/ndo2db.lock
ndo2db_user=nagios
ndo2db_group=nagios
socket_type=unix
socket_name=/usr/local/nagios/var/ndo.sock
use_ssl=0
db_servertype=MySQL
db_host=localhost
db_port=3306
db_name=ndo
db_prefix=nagios_
db_user=root
db_pass=grit_123
max_timedevents_age=1440
max_systemcommands_age=10080
max_servicechecks_age=10080
max_hostchecks_age=10080
max_eventhandlers_age=44640
max_externalcommands_age=44640
```

Comment: You call this "ndo2db.conf", but ndo is looking for "ndo2db.cfg". Is this correct, or just a typo on your part?

Comment: Agreed. Check your filename first.